# what is the max retries for until successful scope in mule 3.4.2

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

what is the max retries for until successful scope in mule 3.4.2?

how many maximum retries we can accoumdate for until successful.is there any limit we have for retries? or else shall I use as many I can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value is [5 retries](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/292d0938eaac5f63219e7c20f564a9bd66c2bed6/core/src/main/java/org/mule/routing/UntilSuccessful.java#L59).

You can change this value with the `maxRetries` attribute on the `until-successfull` scope, for ex:

```
maxRetries="10"
```

This value is an integer so its max value is `2147483647`